# The asp.net MVC controller does not persist my in memory database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm simply entering a name and age on my form and posting it to **ListAll** action in my home controller. But the controller does not **remember** all the names and ages entered, i.e. it doesn't persist it.

P.s. Sorry about the long code, but its all pretty basic and shouldn't complicate things

This is the code in my Index.Html ( where I can enter a person's name and age)

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary();
    @Html.LabelFor(p=>p.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(p=>p.Name)
    @Html.LabelFor(p=>p.Age)
    @Html.EditorFor(p=>p.Age)
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
}
@Html.ActionLink("View All Person", "ListAll");
```

This is my DBContext class,

```
public class TheDB: DbContext
    {
        public List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
    }
```

My person class

```
 public class Person
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Age{get;set;}
    }
```

My controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        TheDB myDB ;
        public HomeController()
        {
            myDB = new TheDB();
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Person person)
        {
            //ignore model validation for now
            myDB.persons.Add(person);
            myDB.SaveChanges(); //update: adding this didn't work either
            return View(person);

        }
        public ActionResult ListAll()
        {            

            return View(myDB.persons.ToList());
        }
```

And finally the ListAll.cshtml which is supposed to show all the people added to the in memory database but **it shows a blank page**

```
@model IEnumerable<HtmlForms.Models.Person>
@using HtmlForms.Models

@foreach(var p in Model )
{
    @p.Name;
    @p.Age;

}
```

What am I missing? If I manually add two **person** objects **IN** the ListAll method and pass that to the View, it works.But the code above doesn't.

Thankyou

Comment: Are you calling `SaveChanges` at any point to commit the changes to the DB?

Comment: I just updated the question. I added it as per your suggestion and strange, it still doesnt work :(

Comment: Where are you storing the instance `TheDB`? If just `myDB = new TheDB();` this will initialize a blank database on each page load - you need to persist it *somewhere*.

Comment: @RGraham TheDB is intialized in the constructor on the controller. It is stored as a global variable, as you can see 3rd line in the Controller code. I thought a public variable will persist ?

Comment: You mention you created index.html... Surely you mean your Index View?

Comment: @Chris, yes I meant index VIEW

Comment: And is your view strongly typed? The first line in your Index View should be `@model Person`

Comment: @ChrisHardie yes it is , but as Sean said below, it is because the instance of a controller is created per request , so my db cannot survive multiple requests :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `myDB` variable is an instance variable for the `HomeController` class. Instance variables are specific to one instance of a class and since a new instance of your `HomeController` class is created every time a request is processed, the in-memory object will be created and then destroyed by the garbage collector when the request is done processing.

You could make the variable `static` and only instantiate it once, like so:

```
static TheDB myDB;

public HomeController()
{
    if (myDB == null)
    {
        myDB = new TheDB();
    }
}
```

However this would only last as long as your application pool runs for, and by default the application pool is stopped after a period of inactivity (as well as errors and other circumstances such as operating system crashes).

If you want your data to be persisted across requests and application pool shutdowns, you will need to use a proper database system or serialise your class to a file somewhere so that it can be reloaded.

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it Note Also, that making the instance static will share it with all users making requests to the page.

Comment: @Sean , so when I use an actual database and use Entityframework, my dbcontext class should be static then?

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it No, Entity Framework is just an object model/access layer on top of your database system. The database system takes care of data persistence for you as most, if not all, database systems store the data in the server's file system.

Answer (score 2):

The lifetime of a controller does not span multiple requests, so it's not possible to let your controller have in-memory database which spans multiple requests.

You could create the database when your application starts (in Global.asax.cs) as a static object. However, it is no more "persisting" than that it will be reset when your application restarts.

Answer (score 1):

The Person class of your model does not contain the primary key field like

eg:    int PersonId { get; Set;}

Entity Framework will work nicely for the entities which contains the key datamember.
So try like this.

```
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id {get; set;}

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Age{get;set;}
    }
```

Also try to use HttpContext.Cache for maintaining data in memory.

```
HttpContext.Cache["Persons"]= MyDB.persons;
```